# Lexmark S305 printer won't print wirelessly over WIFI on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard, lexmark-printer

I have a Lexmark S305 printer which won't print over wifi however it will happily print a test page.

The printer worked fine before upgrading to Snow Leopard.

I understand the Snow Leopard in built drivers won't allow wifi printing so I have installed the latest Lexmark drivers.

I can access the printer wirelessly by the IP Address.

From the print utility I can cause a test page to be printed.

But if I print anything at all from a regular application it just sits forever in the queue and doesn't even error out.

Does anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same (really annoying) problem - I found this worked:

http://binnersoft.com/?p=299

this is from the above link:

1. Uninstall the previous S300 Series software
   .                 .Navigate to [Main HD]/Library/Printers/Lexmark/2009/Lexmark S300-S400 Series folder on Finde
   .                 .Launch the S300-S400 Series Uninstaller and follow the instructions
2. Download the S300SeriesWebInstaller_2.0.0. The web package will be auto-mounted.
3. Double-click Install
4. Follow the instructions on the computer screen
5. The installation process ends with the Printer Setup screen of the Lexmark Setup Assistant.

drivers (300SeriesWebInstaller_2.0.0.) found here:

http://downloads.lexmark.com/downloads/cpd/S300SeriesWebInstaller_2.0.0.dmg